# I want your good

Tags: meaning, nouns

a. I want your good.

Does that mean I want what is good in you, I want you to do what is good, to be kind etc. (I want your good, not your evil.)

or does it mean I want what is good for you?

I suspect it could mean both depending on context.

CASE 1: I want your good not your evil. I want you to give me what is good in you.

CASE 2: I am giving you advice because I want your good. I want what is good for you.

Comment: It's an odd sentence. What's the context?

Comment: Thank you gotube. CASE 1: I want your good not your evil. I want you to give me what is good in you. CASE 2: I am giving you advice because I want your good. I want what is good for you.

Answer (score 3):

That sentence is very unnatural at best, and wrong at worst.

In CASE 1, that sentence makes some sense, but it's a very odd way to phrase it. A more natural way to express this would be, "I want good from you", and it would be even more natural to say, "I expect good things from you."

In CASE 2, that sentence is wrong. The phrase "your good" doesn't have the meaning of "what's good for you".

Answer (score 2):

This expression is wrong. "Good" is primarily an adjective. The related noun is "goodness"

But "I want your goodness" means that you want to take goodness from the person (and leave them with only badness?, it is unclear)

In the first case you might say "I want you to be good"

In the second case "I want what is good for you."

There are uses of "good" as a noun, they are normally heard as part of expressions  "more harm than good",  "a force for good", and not used much to build new sentences.